# Local Variable Memory Consumption

Tags: java, object, arraylist, memory-management

Which approach is better to declare local variable in terms of memory consumption?

```
public List<ResponseObject> mockMethod(RequestObject obj) {
  List<ResponseObject> response = new ArrayList<>();
  if(condition1) {
    response = dataManipulativeMethod1(obj);
    return response;
  } else if(condition2) {
     response = dataManipulativeMethod2(obj);
     return response;
  } else if(condition3) {
     response = dataManipulativeMethod3(obj);
     return response;
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
public List<ResponseObject> mockMethod(RequestObject obj) {
  if(condition1) {
    List<ResponseObject> response = dataManipulativeMethod1();
    return response;
  } else if(condition2) {
     List<ResponseObject> response = dataManipulativeMethod2();
     return response;
  } else if(condition3) {
     List<ResponseObject> response = dataManipulativeMethod3();
     return response;
  }
}
```

Since only one *IF block* is going to run per call to *mockMethod*. I am confused how java manages ***memory of response list*** in above two scenarios?

***Also which approach is better in case tons of request hit to mockMethod at an instant?***

Comment: no need to even declare ur custom list . U can just write this : 

`return dataManipulativeMethod1();`

Comment: Unless you're seeing `StackOverflowErrot` there is no reason to even think about this. And if you are seeing a stack overflow, there's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: @Parsifal -> I am not getting any sort of `Error`. Its just I am trying to learn and write high quality code with less memory consumption.

Comment: It is however pointless (in 1st example) to initialize the variable with an empty array list that you never use.  Your code is incomplete, so maybe you intend to return the empty list if none of the conditions are true.  If so, allocate the arraylist then.

Comment: You don't need the variable at all.  `return dataManipulativeMethod2(obj)` etc.  But that's just a matter of writing succinct (thus clearer) code, rather than a concern for memory use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference.

In both examples, the Java Virtual Machine will allocate the memory of `response` on the stack. When the method returns and the method frame is popped from the stack, all of the local variables become eligible for garbage collection and will (likely) be freed soon.

Comment: The variable on the stack is not garbage-collected.  Garbage collection operates on heap objects. Any object that the variable referred to may be eligible for collection, depending on whether there are other references to it (we don't know what the dataManipulativeMethods are doing behind the scenes).